# MT4 - insert image from web

Tags: image, web, display, mql4, metatrader4

Cracking my head around that - is it even possible in a mql4 indicator ? Would love to have an image on my server and display it on my chart through a link.

If it's not doable, then is there any option to display an image in mt4 without the user having access to the image?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SOF!
Well, it is doable I believe, but never tried.

What you need:
* request a picture as a set of bytes, an example is [here](https://docs.mql4.com/en/common/webrequest)
* draw an object (type = [OBJ_BITMAP](https://docs.mql4.com/en/constants/objectconstants/enum_object/obj_bitmap) once you have it;
* your own webserver that returns a picture (at list for tests, but you may found some resources online, there must be plenty of them who wish to share their pictures)
In order to go forward, show your MCVE code to get more help.

Comment: Where are my manners ! Good morning SOF ! :) Altough have been writing from another account previously, I now have a proper account so....but still, good to be here ! again..! 

Anyways - WebRequest - indeed it worked. Downloaded the image from the server and then can do anything with it.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: my appologies, I corrected the plot of the answer several times, but missed the first line :) Corrected now. Welcome!